# How can I extract "GROUP-ID", "LANGUAGE" and "INSTREAM-ID" from ts using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, caption, video-subtitles

I am trying to get the captions from a segment from a live feed. I am running the command

`ffmpeg -i seg-1077853030-v1-a1.ts`

Output

`Input #0, mpegts, from 'seg-109853030-v1-a1.ts':
Duration: 00:00:06.01, start: 57867.901133, bitrate: 2649 kb/s
Program 1

```
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 98 kb/s
Stream #0:2[0x102]: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)`
```

My question  is what command should I run  to print out the caption file with the track metadata including label and language.

Comment: If it's EIA-608 it might work with `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i movie=input.ts[out+subcc]  -map 0:1  output.srt` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169910/can-ffmpeg-extract-closed-caption-data)

Comment: How do I find this? #EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=CLOSED-CAPTIONS,GROUP-ID="CC",LANGUAGE="eng",NAME="English",INSTREAM-ID="CC1"

Comment: In-stream CC1 is EIA-608 so give the command a try.

Comment: Thx but   Im not sure what the command would look like...

Comment: Thx that worked! But I dont see fields  like "GROUP-ID", "LANGUAGE" and  "NSTREAM-ID" in the  srt file that was generated . What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MPEG-TS file is a HLS segment then just parse the HLS master playlist to retrieve the values.
If your input is captured from a live broadcast then read on.

1. `GROUP-ID`

It's up to you to set this value in the HLS playlist to indicate the rendition's group.

See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216#section-4.3.4.1.1

2. `LANGUAGE`

This is where things get a bit more complicated.

[image]

CEA-608 captions do not include the language code.

For CEA-708 and 608 over 708 this is indicated as part of the ATSC Program and System Information Protocol (PSIP) tables which should be present in the PMT and EIT.

[image: Caption Service Descriptor]

[image: Caption Service Descriptor (concluded)]

- `cc_type` - `0` for 608, `1` for 708
- `line21_field` - when `cc_type` is `0`: `0` for field 1 (which includes channels CC1 and CC2) and `1` for field 2 (which includes channels CC3 and CC4)
- `caption_service_number` - when `cc_type` is `1`

3. `INSTREAM-ID`

This can be either `CC1`, `CC2` (field 1), `CC3`, `CC4` (field 2) for CEA-608 - where CC1 and CC2 carry normal and easy-reader captions for the primary language and CC3 and CC4 for the secondary language - or in the form `SERVICEn` for CEA-708 services.

These should be advertised in the CSD (see above), if present.

I don't think FFmpeg extracts these by default so you'll either need to extend it or write an MPEG-TS parser to retrieve the information. There are a few libs for parsing MPEG-TS and for dealing with captions (ex: [libcaption](https://github.com/szatmary/libcaption) by fellow StackOverflow user @szatmary).

If you just want to extract the captions use FFmpeg or [ccextractor](https://www.ccextractor.org)

If you want to do it manually you could use some software like [DVBInspector](http://www.digitalekabeltelevisie.nl/dvb_inspector/) to see the PSI contents:

[image: DVBInspector CSD]